# message.createdAt gives too much info (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, discord, discord.js

When using message.createdAt, it returns a huge string of information about the time a message was send.
Example output: `Sat Aug 01 2020 12:23:56 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`

Is there a way to shorten this huge info into just: `Sat Aug 01 2020 12:23:56`?

I thought of splitting it by " " and then concat the first 5 elements of the array, is there a better idea than:

```
const time = msg.createdAt.toString();
const time_array = time.split(" ");
const time_str = time_array.reduce((sum, element) => sum+element);
```

Comment: I think you need to set as date object and look at formatting it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date . It is standard date with timezone. Not really too much info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library

```js
const dateCreated = moment(msg.createdAt)
console.log(dateCreated.format("DD/MM/YYYY LTS"))
// 01/08/2020 3:07:44 PM
```

[Moment's Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 2):

Since Discord API attribute [createdAt](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=createdAt) returns a Date Object, why don't you just convert your Date to localeString() ?

```js
const msg = { createdAt : new Date() };


// Demo
const time = msg.createdAt.toLocaleString();
console.log(time);
```